# Material Design Dropdown Menu, how to change something in trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using dropdown menu plugin in my project similar to google's dotted menu.
Here's the link: 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Material-Design-Dropdown-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-menu-js.html

I want to do actions in element which called menu, but I don't know how to code this in jQuery.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input" />
  <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle" id="menu-toggle1">
    <i class="material-icons">MENU 1</i>
  </a>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input" />
  <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle" id="menu-toggle2">
    <i class="material-icons">MENU 2</i>
  </a>
</div>

<!--  MENU -->
<ul class="menu" data-menu data-menu-toggle="#menu-toggle1, #menu-toggle2">
  <li>
    <button>Change this input value to 1</button>
   </li>
   <li>
    <button>Change this input value to 2</button>
  </li>

</ul>
<!--  MENU -->
```

The best explanation of my problem will be this pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpyQvx

Comment: So for example when you click the first button something happen and when you click the  second button something else happen or what?

Comment: I think that the point is these buttons have to change input value depending where menu was called. If in wrapper with #menu-toggle2, change input value there etc.